# Персонаж проваливается под текстуры в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Реализовываю эффект пружинки(подкидывание персонажа), вроде все ок, но иногда(где то 1 раз из 7) проваливается под текстуры и улетает вниз к бесконечности. В чем причина такого бага? Коллайдеры на всех блоках стоят, "Is trigger" не включен, может слишком большая инерция и надо больше одного блока ставить на "дорожку"?

UPD1: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дай угодаю... фпс говно, а коллайдер персонажа мелкий.

Comment: Займитесь отладкой ..

Comment: я надеюсь у вас коллайдеры не на каждый блок?

Answer (score 0):

Вполне возможно по какой-то причине  юнита резко и на большой скорости сначала кидает вниз, из-за чего юнити, обрабатывая покадровое замечает столкновения с полом и персонаж улетает вниз. И если можно, то прикрепи пожалуйста скрин пружины.

Comment: добавил, а что можно сделать в такой ситуации?

Comment: Ну лично я бы делал скрипт для пружины, где только анимация. И сверху на самой пружине еще один пустой дочерний объект, при соприкосновении с которым игрока подкидывает при помощи AddForce.